# React hooks child component useEffect executes first, before parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I' learning about react hooks useEffect and I'm confused on the order of execution of useEffect. In the console it tells me that the ChildComponent "child component" console.log was executed first, then the "on mount" useEffect, and lastly the "parent component" was logged. I was expecting "on mount" to be logged first, then "parent component", and lastly the "child component".
Can anyone explain why the child logs first, or why things execute this way?

Fields is a simple array of objects

```
const fields = [
    {
        id    : 'month',
        title : 'Month'
    },
    {
        id    : 'amount',
        title : 'Amount'
    },
    {
        id    : 'year',
        title : 'Year'
    },
];
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function ParentComponent(props) {
    const [fields, setFields] = useState(props.fields || []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('on mount');
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('parent component');
    }, [fields]);

    function randomString() {
        return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
    }



    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={() => setFields([...fields,...[{id: randomString(), title: randomString()}]])}
            >Change field</button>
            <ChildComponent fields={fields}/>
        </div>
    );
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('child component')
    }, [props.fields]);
    return (<div>
        {props.fields.map(({ id, title }) => <div key={id} className="field">{title}</div>)}
    </div>)
}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s practically the same order of event bubbling. First top-down for the rendering, then bottom-up for the mounting/effect execution. useEffect is not setTimeout, it’s more like event handling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same as [javascript event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) which means when it runs, it calls all the `ParentComponent` functions, which will call and render `ChildComponent`, once the inner-est function is called (child rendered) it will bubble up to the top again, which now the `ParentComponent's` `useEffect` kicks in and will be in order.
[image]

I have modified a bit your code, so you can see more the order I'm referring
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-jennings-9hwwv?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: OK I think I understand. As it's mounting the child components of the parent this causes the children to call their useEffect functions, and when they are all done the parent is the last one to call useEffect?

Comment: Yes, and the order of useEffect would be from inner-est to the most outter one. and also that is the reason why the argument of useEffect is actually is an function (so js could "queue" it for later)

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: side question, does the component unamount when an update is made to state? My returned function in useEffect gets executed after state is updated.

Comment: it depends, usually won't unmount when prop changes. but  if for example you return a null then return childComponent eg. loading or swaping ChildComponent, it  might cause that. feel free to open another question for that

Comment: Is there a way we could force parent to render first, after that only child renders?