# How to run a function just after parent component "useEffect" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a react app with parent component app.js and a child component homepage.js.

So when I refresh the page useEffect hook from homepage.js runs first and then app.js useEffect runs but I have some functionality that is dependent on app.js useEffect I want that code run automatically after page refresh and after the useEffect in app.js.

Comment: take a look at this answer, you might get your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352375/what-is-the-correct-order-of-execution-of-useeffect-in-react-parent-and-child-co

Comment: Earlier I was looking at that document it was very helpful but I actually need a way to execute few lines of codes after execution of parent component useEffect. and because the child component useEffect runs before parent component useEffect on refresh so I can not put it there. Thanks for quick reply!

Comment: Take a look at this answer, you might get your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340168/react-hooks-child-component-useeffect-executes-first-before-parent-component

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute parent component code first then in parent instead of using useEffect() execute that code in useMemo()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).